# Invoke command with a dynamic list of variable assignments in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Defining a couple variables like this:

```sh
VARS="VAR1=1 VAR2=2"
```

Then I want to feed these variables to the command that follows. I could do it like:

```sh
VAR1=1 VAR2=2 mycommand
```

That works fine but I am looking to set those local scoped variables dynamically, like:

```sh
$ $VARS mycommand
VAR1=1: command not found
```

That seems to execute `$VARS` as command which is not what is intended.

Comment: Basically you asks for dynamic code stored in a variable. There is `eval` for this and include, with all the evil of dynamic code. Unless there is a valid reason without any alternative to use dynamic code; it should be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `env`.

```
envvars=(VAR1=1 VAR2=2)
env "${envvars[@]}" mycommand
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Bash function that takes a command and runs it with desired variables.

```sh
function with_my_variables {
  VAR1=1 VAR2=2 $@
}
```

In the code above, `$@` expands to all the function parameters.

Then, you can call it like this:

```sh
with_my_variables mycommand --my-arguments
```